# How to push back a data that the string iterator is pointing to into the vector of string

Tags: c++, string, vector, iterator

I want to tokenize a string and add to a vector, but all I can do now is just accessing them via iterator, shown below.

```
vector<string> ExprTree::tokenise(string expression){

    vector<string> vec;
    std::string::iterator it = expression.begin();

    while ( it != expression.end()) {

        cout << "it test " << (*it) << endl;
        vec.push_back(*it); // wrong!
        it++;
    }
```

when I put `(10 + 10) * 5`
the output is

```
( 
1
0 
+ 
1
0
) 
*
5
```

which is what I want, but how can I actually add them to the vector?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the iterator of `std::string` points to a `char`, so `*it` is not a `std::string`, but a `char`, which can't be `push_back`ed into the `std::vector<std::string>` directly.

You can change it to

```
vec.push_back({*it});     // construct a temporary string (which contains *it) to be added
```

or use `emplace_back` instead:

```
vec.emplace_back(1, *it); // add a string contains 1 char with value *it
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't be  mistaken, you won't push the space, do you?
I create a function called `tokenise` as follow which needs the `text` and string container `vec`.

```
void tokenize(const std::string text, std::vector<std::string>& vec) {
  for(auto &it : text) {
    if(isspace(it) == false) {
      vec.push_back(std::string(1,it));
    }
  }
}
```

Just call this function as you wish. The implementation should be like this :

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
std::string text = "10 + 10) * 5";
tokenize(text, vec);
for(auto &it : vec){
  std::cout << it << std::endl;
}
```

The output will be the same as you want. This code would require `cctype` header.